# Entity framework Many-to-Many relations

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to find a way to make a collection of entities (something like this):

```
Students:

| StudentID |   Name    |
-------------------------
|    1      |    Joe    |
|    2      |   Jack    |


StudentsCourses:

| StudentID |  CourseID |
-------------------------
|    1      |    1      |
|    2      |    1      |
|    2      |    2      |


Courses:

|  CourseID |    Name     |
---------------------------
|    1      |   Math I    |
|    2      |   Math II   |
```

into an IEnumerable of this:

```cs
class StudentDTO
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<CourseDTO> Courses {get; set;}
}

class CourseDTO
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

using Linq and EF in C#. I have been looking at the GroupBy() method but i cannot see how to make it "fit" my needs. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

So far i have the follwing query:

```cs
var result = from s in db.Students
             from sc in db.StudentsCourses.Where(x => x.StudentID == sc.StudentID)
             from c in db.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == sc.CourseID)
             select new StudentDTO()
             {
                 ID = s.StudentID,
                 Name = s.Name
                 Courses = ???
             };
```

How can i make a list out of all the Courses on each student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move two `from`s into the `select`:

```
from s in db.Students
select new StudentDTO()
{
    ID = s.StudentID,
    Name = s.Name
    Courses = from sc in db.StudentsCourses
                           .Where(x => x.StudentID == s.StudentID)
              from c in db.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == sc.CourseID)
              select new CourseDto { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name  }
};
```

However, it is recommended to have navigation properties in your classes: at least `Student.StudentCourses` and `StudentCourse.Course`. So you can do:

```
from s in db.Students
select new StudentDTO()
{
    ID = s.StudentID,
    Name = s.Name
    Courses = from sc i s.StudentsCourses
              select new CourseDto { ID = sc.Course.ID,
                                     Name = sc.Course.Name
                                   }
};
```